# Помогите если я добавляю 4 параметр slidesToShow: то у меня пропадают стрелки

Tags: javascript, slider, slick.js, slider-slick.js

Если я добавляю 4 элемента то на моем слайдере пропадают стрелки, я пробовал loop: true, Помогите!

[image: добавил 3 элемента]
[image: добавил 4 элемента]

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.header__burger').click(function(event) {
        $('.header__burger, .header__list').toggleClass('active');
        $('body').toggleClass('lock');
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.slider').slick({
    arrows:true,
    adaptiveHeight: true,
    slidesToShow: 3,
    infinite: true,
    slidesToScroll: 1
    });
});

    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css"/>

    <title>Startup Web-studio</title>
</head>
<body>
    @@include('_header.html')
    @@include('_services.html')
    @@include('_about.html')
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

    <section class="about">
    <div class="container">
        <h1>About Us</h1>
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
            consetetur sadipscing elitr amet</h3>
        <div class="about__main">
            <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing 
                elitr, sediam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt 
                ut labore et dolore aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. 
                At vero eos etaccusam et justo dolores et ea rebum. 
                Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est 
                 ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor et dolore 
                 aliquyam erat.
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum eat.</h4>
                <h4>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,
                    sediam nonumy eirtempor invidunt ut 
                    labore et dolore aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. 
                    At vero eos eaccusamet justo dolores et ea rebum. 
                    Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor et dolore 
                    aliquyam erat. 
                    <p>Loreipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor et.</p>
                </h4>
        </div>
        <div class="slider">
            <div class="slider__item">
                <img src="img/1.png">
            </div>
            <div class="slider__item">
                <img src="img/2.png">
            </div>
            <div class="slider__item">
                <img src="img/3.png">
            </div>
            <div class="slider__item">
                <img src="img/4.png">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

    .about {
        background-color: #f8f8f8;
        width: 100%;
        height: 850px;
        padding-top: 100px;
                h4 {
                    font-size: 12px;
                    font-family: "RobotoSlab";
                    color: rgb(85, 85, 85);
                    line-height: 1.714;
                    text-align: left;  
                    font-weight: 500;
                    margin: 0 0 0 35px;
                }
            }
        }
        h1 {
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 20px;
            font-family: "Montserrat";
            color: rgb(85, 85, 85);
            text-transform: uppercase;
            font-weight: 600;             
        }
        h1:after {
            content: "";
            height: 2px;
            position: relative;
            bottom: 25px; 
            width: 50px;
            background-color: #555555;
            display: block;
            margin: 50px auto 0;
        }
        h3 {
            
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 16px;
            font-family: "RobotoSlab";
            color: rgb(85, 85, 85);                
        }
        .about__main {
            display: flex;
            margin: 75px 0 0 65px;
            justify-content: space-around;
            h4 {
                font-size: 14px;
                font-family: "RobotoSlab";
                color: rgb(85, 85, 85);
                line-height: 1.714;
                text-align: left;  
                font-weight: 500;
                margin: 0 0 0 35px;
            }
        }
        .slick-list {
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .slick-track {
            display: flex;
            align-items: flex-start;
        }
        .slider {
            position: relative;
            margin-top: 75px;
            margin-left: 100px;
            img {
                height: 225px;
            }
            .slick-arrow {
                position: absolute;
                font-size: 0;
                top: 45%;
                z-index: 10;
                height: 30px;
                width: 30px;
                background: #c0301c;
            }
            .slick-prev {
                transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
                left: 0;
                background-image: url('../img/left.png');
                background-position: 45% 45%;
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
            }
            .slick-prev:hover {
                background-image: url('../img/left.png');
                background-color: #8e8e8e;
            }
            .slick-next {
                right: 0;
                background-image: url('../img/right.png');
                background-position: 55% 45%;
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
            }   
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Slick-слайдер прячет стрелки, если перематывать нечего, у вас всего четыре слайда и все они показаны, добавьте ещё один и стрелки появятся.

Comment: но он мне не нужен, у меня по макету нужно 4 слайда. Как быть?

Comment: На меньших разрешениях, когда вы  slidesToShow выставите 3 и меньше, стрелки появятся.

Comment: Спасибо надо попробовать

Comment: Если я уменьшаю количество слайдов, у меня как и должно нет 4 слайдов. Как сделать так чтобы были и стрелки и 4 слайда, а по середине не было белой точки пустого слайда? У меня по макету должно стоять 4

Answer (score 0):

Нашел способ VariableWidth: true.